# Docker - How do I find the correct paths for files once build has been initiated?

Tags: node.js, docker, unix

**Error:**

/bin/sh: 1: BrowserStackLocalunix: not found

**Host directory ls:**

```
$ ls
BrowserStackLocal   BrowserStackLocalunix   codecept.conf.js    docker-compose.yml  features    mochawesome-report  output  pageactions
BrowserStackLocal.exe   browserstack    data    dockerfile  helpers node_modules    package-lock.json   pageobjects
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN [“mkdir”, “-p”, “/app”]

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN BrowserStackLocalunix
```

**Command:**

```
docker build -t react:v1.0 .
```

Comment: Just for grins, does the first line of `BrowserStackLocalunix` have something line `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: thanks for the response!

VScode reports "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding"

Opening it anyway looks clearly encoded, first line is : ELF> with a ton of ? chars.

Comment: Have you set the execute bit? `chmod +x BrowserStackLocalunix`?

Comment: Thats a helpful suggestions thanks, I tired to change the dockerfile to

```RUN chmod +x BrowserStackLocalunix --key nLGBbtgFYjTqoZyLA95q --force-local```

And I actually got a different error that said:

```chmod: unrecognized option '--key'
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.```

so now I am trying:

```RUN chmod +x "BrowserStackLocalunix --key nLGBbtgFYjTqoZyLA95q --force-local"```

Comment: That produced ```chmod: cannot access 'BrowserStackLocalunix --key nLGBbtgFYjTqoZyLA95q --force-local': No such file or directory```

Now I want to try chmod on it first and then running it maybe?

Comment: chmod seemed to work but results are similar:

```Step 7/9 : RUN chmod +x BrowserStackLocalunix
 ---> Running in 191e472c6a8e
Removing intermediate container 191e472c6a8e
 ---> 6f7551917a53
Step 8/9 : RUN BrowserStackLocalunix --key nLGBbtgFYjTqoZyLA95q --force-local
 ---> Running in 4df8662e3215
/bin/sh: 1: BrowserStackLocalunix: not found```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving from a windows to a linux system, you need to ensure file permissions are correct by adding a `chmod` for your program:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN [“mkdir”, “-p”, “/app”]
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["chmod", "gou+x", "/app/BrowserStackLocalunix" ]
RUN ["/app/BrowserStackLocalunix", "--key", "nLGBbtgFYjTqoZyLA95q", "--force-local"]
```

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I went from OSX to lunix.

Comment: When in doubt, specify the path absolutely. :)